# Life cycle of the application: How to do some clean jobs when the process is terminated?

Tags: android, process, lifecycle

My application is very straightforward,  Main Activity -> activity 1 -> activity 2, and there is another worker thread who is doing some downloading jobs.  And they are started within the same process.

I want the downloading thread is not terminated until all the activities are destroyed, or at the end of the process. In Java, it is very simple: it will be OK by adding some clean code in the main method. But I don't know what is the right way in Android. Because every activity is possible to be recycled by the system, I don't know where to put the clean code of the worker thread, and I also dont't know what is the end point of the total application.

Could anyone give me some ideas? thanks.

Comment: Under android 2.1, Application.onTerminate() doesn't seem to work. I only have the choice to add a reference count for worker thread(or Service). When the reference count is decreased to zero, terminate the worker thread.

Comment: I found I had been confused by quitting an android application. I decided to change the worker thread to a Service, which puts clean code in its onDestroy method. Explicitly add a menu command to exit the total application just like any GUI programme in PC. Thanks a lot for those helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure if it helps, but you can start a service in your main activity and have all clean up code in the Service's onDestroy method. the service will be destroyed when your application will be destroyed

onTerminate only works on emulator - it is stated in the docs.

Comment: Thanks a lot. After I chose to close the application, the service along with the process survived much longer time than my expectation. I come to understand the differences between android and PC.

Comment: do you actually close the application? i believe you cannot just close the application. it is still in the memory. it will get killed by android later when phone needs to free resources etc. if you want your service to end when your app goes to background, you should assume using onPause/onResume methods of current activity. read about activity lifecycle in android docs.. maybe creating an abstract activity class with onPause/onResume/etc methods taking care of the service and deriving all your activities from that class.. (not 100% sure if this is a good approach though =)

Comment: btw, making "exit" button is a bad practice in android as far as i know. OS should take care of that, not user